# C# WPF Привязка свойств DataGridColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Добрый день и с Новым годом) Имеется проблема, которую я банально не знаю как решить.
Имею проект WPF с MVVM уклоном. Имеется таблица с колонками. Я хочу сделать сохранение и восстановление при запуске программы свойств этих колонок: размер, положение, видимость и прочее.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RPS, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      IsReadOnly="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                          material:DataGridAssist.CellPadding="0 5 3 5"
                          material:DataGridAssist.ColumnHeaderPadding="4 2 2 2"
                          Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">

                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DataGrid, Path=SelectedItems}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                     
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="##" Binding="{Binding TestNumber}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="State">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Width="15" VerticalAlignment="Center" ToolTip="{Binding Message}" Height="15"></Image>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            
                           
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ColSize" Header="Size" Binding="{Binding Size}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ColName" Header="File Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ColVehicle" Header="Vehicle" Binding="{Binding Vehicle}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ColVersion" Header="Version" Binding="{Binding Version}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ColDateTime" Header="DateTime" Binding="{Binding DateTime, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss\}}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ColUnix" Header="Unix" Binding="{Binding ArenaCreationTime}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                           
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                        
                    </DataGrid>
```

Для хранения данных о колонке я сделал класс:

```
public class DataGridColumn
{
public string Text { get; set; }
public string SubText { get; set; }
public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
public int Width { get; set; }
public int Position { get; set; }
}
```

Во ViewModel я создаю коллекцию

```
public List<DataGridColumn> Columns { get; set; }
```

Соответственно, мне нужно как-то связать каждую колонку с этой коллекцией. Как это сделать?

Comment: 1) Таблица ReadOnly - то есть редактирование данных не предполагается, верно? 2) Зачем вам InteractionTrigger, если можно вызвать нужный метод из сеттера `SelectedItem`? 3) Количество колонок фиксировано и всегда одно и то же, верно?

Comment: В целом выглядит, что `DataGrid` просто не предназначена для такой операции, придется попотеть, вот например - [ширина колонки](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46788976/12888024) примерно так делается.

Comment: С учетом того, что вам не надо редактировать данные прямо в таблице, проще наверное написать свой контрол, который будет поддерживать все что вам нужно. Что касается сохранения данных, очень просто сохранить в JSON `string text = JsonSerializer.Serialize(Columns)`, где `Columns` - коллекция с данными для колонок, далее просто запишите в файл `File.WriteAllText("file.json", text)`.

Comment: Кстати, название класса `DataGridColumn` конфликтует с [`System.Windows.Controls.DataGridColumn`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn?view=netframework-4.8), назовите класс по-другому.

Comment: Класс переименую, таблица действительно ReadOnly, а вот позиция колонок может меняться. Проблема в том, что я не могу динамически создавать колонки из кода, у меня много столбцов с разными  триггерами и стайлами (по крайней мере я не знаю как это можно добавлять через код). InteractionTrigger делал по примеру, т.к. нужен был лист из выделенных строк. Насчет своего контрола, хотел бы посмотреть пример.

Comment: На базе `ListView` ищи те примеры для `UserControl`.

Comment: Не скинете пример? Не могу найти, либо неправильно гуглю.